# Cannot start mysql server: "Unit mysqld.service could not be found" "Job for mysql.service failed"

Tags: server, mysql

I have a problem starting MySQL server 
when I type this command

```
service mysqld status
```

I get this output:

```
Unit mysqld.service could not be found
```

also:

```
$ sudo service mysql start
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details
```

and

```
$ sudo mysql -u root -p
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```